# How to show diacritic accent mark in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox, diacritics

Inside my WPF application there is a `RichTextBox` and by showing its text content in VS Immediate Window there is a `f` character with a circumflex accent, but in the display window only renders the character without the diacritic.

This two methods set and retrieve the RTB content:

```
Function rtbText(rtb As RichTextBox) As String
    Dim txtRng As New TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd)
    Return txtRng.Text
End Function
Sub rtbSetText(rtb As RichTextBox, s As String)
    Dim flowDoc As New FlowDocument
    Dim r As New Run(s)
    Dim p As New Paragraph
    p.Inlines.Add(r)
    flowDoc.Blocks.Add(p)
    rtb.Document = flowDoc
End Sub
```

The Immediate Window reports for RTB control `rtbString`:

`?rtbtext(rtbString)`

`"f̂(x,y,t)=1/(n*h_x*h_y*h_t)¡∑_i=1^n▒k(x−X_i)/(h_x)×k(y−Y_i)/(h_y)×k(t−T_i)/(h_t)" & vbCrLf`

The first character f̂ is present in `rtbString` but it is not showing properly:

[image]

Comment: Can you check what font family is used, please? Just print the `rtb.Document.FontFamily` at the end line of the `rtbSetText()` method. More likely the problem is related to the used font.

Comment: It is Verdana ?rtbString.FontFamily .tostring "Verdana"

Comment: Arial font works Ok, 'Courier New' fails the same as Verdana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the font family related problem. Try to set it, for example, to `Segoe UI`:

```xml
<RichTextBox FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" ...
```

---

When a font doesn't contain the required character, the system tries to adapt the current font and does not always get the expected result.

Comment: @XavierJunqué: I would advise you to modify your `rtbSetText()` method to set the required font for the new `Run()`. This way, adding the specific text will not affect other parts of the document.

Comment: @XavierJunqué: This is depend on the Windows setting and set of fonts used by the Windows. For example, on my Windows the `Arial` font doesn't show expected result. More precisely, it's related to the [Windows code page` ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)

Comment: Then, how to assure that deploying the application the user's Windows will show correctly?

Comment: This is a good question! For example see [Packaging Fonts with Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: So, I understand the problem has to do with the font and not really with the O.S.

Comment: Exactly. If an application uses special characters you can't be sure that suitable font will be available on the user's computer. Therefore, using the application embedded font is good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have embedded Tahoma font and set it in the new Run().